# Ignore unittests that depend on success of other tests

Tags: python, unit-testing

When writing unit tests, it often happens that some tests sort of "depend" on other tests.

For example, lets suppose I have a test that checks I can instantiate a class.  I have other tests that go right ahead and instantiate it and then test other functionality.

Lets also suppose that the class fails to instantiate, for whatever reason.

This results in a ton of tests giving errors.  This is bad, because I can't see where the problem really is.  What I need is a way of skipping these tests if my instantiation test has failed.

Is there a way of doing this with Python's unittest module?

If this isn't what I should do, what should I do so as to see where the problem really is when something breaks?

Comment: I was going to comment and say that "no unit tests should rely on other unit tests" but your constructor example is a perfect counter argument.

Comment: Try using the [`unittest.skipIf`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures) decorator.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, contrary to my comment above, I think what you need is a `setUpClass` method. From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass),

> If an exception is raised during a setUpClass then the tests in the class are not run and the tearDownClass is not run. [...] If the exception is a [SkipTest](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.html#unittest.SkipTest) exception then the class will be reported as having been skipped instead of as an error.

So something like this should work (I'm sure it could be neater):

```
class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # run the constructor test
        if constructor_test_failed:
            raise unittest.SkipTest("Constructor failed")

    def test_other_stuff(self):
        # will get run after setUpClass if it succeeded
```

Comment: Ok, but how about worse chains of dependencies?

Lets say I have a function that creates a file.  I first want to check that this function executes at all.  Then I want to test the existence of the file.  Then I want to test the contents of the file.

Comment: @PaulEtherton - part of the problem is that `unittest` makes no promises about what order the tests will be executed in. (My guess is that it's the order they appear in the class's `__dict__.items()`). So you have no idea whether the test you're depending on has even been executed yet, let alone whether it passed.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you might have to live with it (or try hacking on the test class's dict by using a metaclass to replace it with an `OrderedDict`, but that's too crazy to countenance!). If your test classes are small and your code is decoupled it shouldn't be too much of a big deal, right? If your three file test functions form a single class, then it shouldn't be too hard to find where to look when all three of them fail together. Right...? (You may say that I'm a dreamer...)

Answer (score 1):

I have no suggestion how to avoid running "dependent" tests, but I have a suggestion how you might better live with them: Make the dependencies more apparent and therefore make it easier to analyse test failures later.  One simple possibility is the following:

- In the test-code, you put the tests for the lower-level aspects at the top of the file, and the more dependent tests further to the bottom. Then, when several tests fail, first look at the test that is closest to the top of the file.